# Reduce set of symbolic equations to linearly independent subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a set of symbolic equations $f_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=0$ in several variables, for example

```
f1=x+y-z;
f2=x-y+z;
f3=3x-y+z;
```

I would like to apply a function `LinIndep[{f1,f2,f3}]` such that the output reduces the system to only a set of linearly independent functions. So, for the above the output might be:

```
LinIndep[{f1,f2,f3}]
```

> {x+y-z,x-y+z}

It is OK if the function finds a different set of linearly independent functions. The point is to reduce the number of equations. I know that `GroebnerBasis` does this. However, a Groebner basis calculation does more than I need to do here and becomes really slow for bigger equations with symbolic coefficients. All I want is literally check for linear dependence and truncate the set accordingly. Is there a way to do this efficiently?

Comment: If all your equations are linear, you can construct the coefficient matrix and use `RowReduce`. But you say you may have symbolic coefficients: in this case the linear dependencies are not given. For instance, `{f1, f2} = {x + y, x + a*y}` are dependent if `a == 1` and independent otherwise.

Comment: The symbolic coefficients are expected to be such that linear dependence, if present, would be valid for all possible parameter values.

Comment: `In[955]:= 
DeleteCases[
  RowReduce[
   CoefficientArrays[{f1, f2, f3}, {x, y, z}][[2]]], {0 ..}].{x, y, z}

Out[955]= {x, y - z}`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau wow, this works great! I wonder, what is this double point notation you used in there `{0 ..}`?

Comment: It just means `Repeated`. Used in Mathematica pattern matching. You can see this by checking the full form: `FullForm[0 ..]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following, although I have tested it only with your example, so it would be interesting to explore its robustness further.

```
Clear[linIndep]
linIndep[list_List] :=
  Module[
    {coeffarray, reduced},
    coeffarray = CoefficientArrays[list, Variables[list]][[2]];
    reduced = LatticeReduce[coeffarray];
    reduced.Variables[list]
  ]

list = {x + y - z, x - y + z, 3 x - y + z};
linIndep[list]

(* Out: {x + y - z, -x + y - z} *)
```