# Given n-polynomials, how can I find the linearly independent polynomials?

Tags: list-manipulation, linear-algebra, code-request

Suppose I have $f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_n$ equations in $k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$, i.e., the polynomials $f_i$ consist $n$ variables including degree. For example $n=3$, one of the example of $f_1$ would be $f_1 = x^2 +y^4 - z^2 + 1$

For given $n$ polynomials $\{f_1, \cdots, f_n\}$ I want to construct linear independent polynomials out of this.

I found one particular code in the [mathematica stackexchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96329/reduce-set-of-symbolic-equations-to-linearly-independent-subset) with the code

```
Clear[linIndep]
linIndep[list_List] :=
Module[
{coeffarray, reduced},
coeffarray = CoefficientArrays[list, Variables[list]][[2]];
reduced = LatticeReduce[coeffarray];
reduced.Variables[list] ]

list = {x + y - z, x - y + z, 3 x - y + z};
linIndep[list]

(* Out: {x + y - z, -x + y - z} *)
```

But this only holds for this type of example.

For example, it does not work for some complicated lists which are only linear in 20 variables.

```
 list2={-x1 y1 - x2 y2 - x3 y3 - x4 y4, -x2 y5 - x3 y6 - x4 y7, x1 y5 - x3 y8 - x4 y9, -x4 y10 + x1 y6 + x2 y8,x3 y10 + x1 y7 + x2 y9, -x5 y2 - x6 y3 - x7 y4, -x1 y1 - x5 y5 -x6 y6 - x7 y7, -x1 y2 - x6 y8 - x7 y9, -x7 y10 - x1 y3 + x5 y8,  x6 y10 - x1 y4 + x5 y9, x5 y1 - x8 y3 - x9 y4, -x2 y1 - x8 y6 - x9 y7, -x2 y2 - x5 y5 - x8 y8 - x9 y9, -x9 y10 - x2 y3 - x5 y6, x8 y10 - x2 y4 - x5 y7, x6 y1 + x8 y2 - x10 y4, -x3 y1 + x8 y5 - x10 y7, -x3 y2 - x6 y5 -   x10 y9, -x10 y10 - x3 y3 - x6 y6 - x8 y8, -x3 y4 - x6 y7 - x8 y9,  x7 y1 + x9 y2 + x10 y3, -x4 y1 + x9 y5 + x10 y6, -x4 y2 - x7 y5 +   x10 y8, -x4 y3 - x7 y6 - x9 y8, -x10 y10 - x4 y4 - x7 y7 - x9 y9}
```

Given $n$ polynomials with an arbitrary degrees, how one can construct a linear independent one out of this polynomial?

Comment: Isn't this `PolynomialReduce[Variables[list], list, Variables[list]][[All, 2]]` similar to `linIndep[list]`? In the sense that they both tell you that `x = -y + z`

Comment: " I want to construct linear independent polynomials out of this." Any linear combination does not fulfill this. Therefore you may need products.

Comment: You mention “equations” in the first sentence. Are these polynomials to be set equal to zero? If yes, then you may be looking for a [Gröbner basis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html).

Comment: Duplicate of [this recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/279428/basis-for-multivariable-polynomials/279449#279449)?